# Обособление оборота с "как" в значении "в качестве"

Tags: стилистика, как

в школе учили, если "как" в обороте можно заменить словом "словно", то только тогда требуется обособление. Потом выяснилось, что все несколько сложнее. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в данном случае надо ли обособлять оборот с "как"?
**Предлагаем Вам(,) как нашему клиенту(,) услуги со скидкой**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это не просто оборот, это обособленное приложение. В справочнике по стилистике читаем:

> 5. Обособленное приложение может присоединяться союзом как (с дополнительным значением причинности), а также словами по имени, по
>      фамилии, по прозвищу, родом и др., например: Илюше иногда, как резвому
>      мальчику, так и хочется броситься и переделать всё самому (Гончаров);
>      Мне, **как лицу высокопоставленному**, не подобает ездить на конке…
>      (Чехов); Как старый артиллерист, я презираю этот вид холодного
>      украшения (Шолохов) (независимо от того, какой частью речи выражено
>      определяемое слово); …Маленький чернявый лейтенант, по фамилии Жук,
>      привёл батальон к задним дворам той улицы… (Симонов). Но (без
>      интонации обособления): Завёл он себе медвежонка по имени Яша
>      (Паустовский); Мы познакомились с немецким врачом по фамилии Шульц.
>
>    Примечание. Если союз как имеет значение «в качестве», то присоединяемый им оборот не является приложением и не обособляется,
>      например: Полученный ответ рассматривается как согласие ( Ажаев).
>
>    Не
>      обособляется также приложение с союзом как, характеризующее предмет с
>      какой-либо одной стороны, например: Читающая публика успела привыкнуть
>      к Чехову как юмористу (Федин).

https://pravopisanie_i_stilistika.academic.ru/94/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BF

*Предлагаем Вам, как нашему клиенту, услуги со скидкой*.

Здесь есть значение причинности: *Предлагаем Вам, так как Вы являетесь нашим клиентом, услуги со скидкой.*